# Android Studio,ImageView,shows different size image in different size's mobile

Tags: image, android-layout

created an android app which loads pics in ImageView randomly from drawable folder by .setImageResource,but the main problem is image it loads shows correct size image but in different size mobile shows different size image,also in some mobile it covers the screen which hides the buttons etc,
its works fine in my Redmi 2 Prime which is 4.7nch,resolution:720*1280,
but in Samsung Galaxy Grand Neo its hides the entire screen with that image i.e screen size: 5.01 inch
resolution: 480*800
[Samsung grand neo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbAfl.jpg)  
[Redmi 2 screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyNSx.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#4e2f22"
tools:context="com.wordpress.dragontelnetsite.mindreader.SecondActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:background="@drawable/backg">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Next"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="clickedOnPlay2"
        android:background="#4cb076"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/c1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```